# How to add Tab Space before every second line in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to make like this for example:

[image: Text Example]

Also if it is important, this text document will be in Unicode encoding.

Comment: Please, don't post example as image, add the text in your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A|\G).+\R\K(.+(?:\R|\z))`
- Replace with: `\t$1`
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:         # non capture group
  \A        # beginning of file
 |          # OR
  \G        # restart from last match position
)           # end group
.+          # 1 or more any character but newline
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n) 
\K          # forget all we have seen until this position
(           # group 1
  .+        # 1 or more any character but newline
  (?:       # non capture group
    \R      # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n) 
   |        # OR
    \z      # end of file
)           # end group
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: @omari: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Toto +1; try adding a line after the `gggg` (for example `hhhh`) and see if the regex formula still works.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: You're right, I have added the case when last line is even and doesn't have a linebreak. Thank you.